# Formatting string with QGIS Expression builder: separate groups of fours digits with hyphens

Tags: qgis, expression, string, qgis-expression

I'm trying to make a label ruled based. I have a numerical value:

```
123412341234
```

and try  to write an expression to make it look like this:

```
1234-1234-1234
```

I tried using `substr` but I get an error when im trying to join two `substr` with dash between them.

```
substr("NTR_ID", 0, 4) + "-" + substr("NTR_ID", 5, 4)+ "-" + substr("NTR_ID", 9, 4)
```

What is the solution?

[image]

Comment: `"` are necessary when you want to refer to column names/fields, `' ` need to be used around strings.

Answer (score 4):

This expression here splits any string you insert in line 3 in groups of 4, connected with hyphen `-`. In line 3, you can also use a fieldname instead to convert the string in this input field:

```
with_variable (
    'your_string',
    '123412341234', -- insert string or fieldname here
    array_to_string (
        array_foreach(
            generate_series (1, length(@your_string),4),
            substr(@your_string, @element, 4)
        ), 
        '-'
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrectly using double quotes instead of single quotes for string literals. Please read the QGIS user manual about writing expressions https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#writing-an-expression

The correct expression is the following one:

`substr("NTR_ID", 0, 4) + '-' + substr("NTR_ID", 5, 4) + '-' + substr("NTR_ID", 9, 4)`

Answer (score 2):

For splitting inputs with fixed length (here: 12 characters), use this expression (`"input_text"` is the name of the field containing the string you want to format):

```
array_to_string (
    regexp_matches ("input_text",'(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})'),
    '-'
)
```